# ValueError: Argument must be a dense tensor: ((10, 4945), 1024) - got shape [2], but wanted [2, 2]

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

My `keras` model is:

```
        model = Sequential()
        model.add(Embedding(input_dim=(self.BATCH_SIZE,
                                       len(self._tokens)), output_dim=1024))

        model.add(LSTM(128))

        model.add(Dropout(rate=0.5))
        model.add(Dense(len(self._tokens)))
        model.add(Activation('softmax'))
```

and I get an error:

```
ValueError: Argument must be a dense tensor: ((10, 4945), 1024) - got shape [2], but wanted [2, 2].
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing incorrectly. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Change input_dim=(self.BATCH_SIZE, len(self._tokens)) to input_dim=len(self._tokens). You should not provide batch size explicitly here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [keras](https://keras.io/layers/embeddings/) official Documentation, **input_dim** parameter of embedding layer should be the size of the vocabulary, i.e. maximum integer index + 1 (int>0).

So, you code should be:

```
model.add(Embedding(input_dim=len(self._tokens), output_dim=1024))
```

In case, you haven't added **input_length** and **input_shape** parameters in the embedding layer, then

```
input_shape = (None,)
```

else

```
input_shape = (input_length,) # added 'input_length=' parameter
```

For more info check the official code [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/47e1b18c0b7e3ddeef4e9fcded409a55d0479a4f/keras/layers/embeddings.py#L16).